# Liquibase 4.24.0 changed behavior - adding semicolon to end of procs/views in SQL Server

Tags: liquibase

I have an older version of Liquibase in my gitlab runner. Locally, I have upgraded to 4.24.0. The newer version is adding a semicolon to the end of scripts, while the old version is not. Here is a sample comment at the top of a SQL file...

```
 --liquibase formatted sql
 --changeset mtagliaf:views.Tm.vTeam.20000101 id:views.Tm.vTeam.20000101 runOnChange:true stripComments:false splitStatements:true endDelimiter:;;;;;
create or alter view Tm.vTeam as 
   select ...
     from ...
     where ...
;;;;;
```

The same script will add a semicolon to the end if I process using 4.24.0, and leave it off if I use the older version. Is there a way to revert this behavior back to remove the trailing semicolon